# Power Apps Collection: How to access nested table items from collection?

Tags: bulk, office365connectors, powerapps-collection

What I am trying to do is paste a list of user IDs, and resolve the list to the people and then save their info to a collection and eventually write them to SharePoint.

I have a multiline text input control (txtPastedText) that accepts a pasted line-delimited list of IDs which are also listed in Office365 as MailNickname. Then I have a Button that executes a ForAll to add them to a collection (UserIDList), but the collection creates a table with two columns: @odata.nextLink and value which is a table. How do I iterate through the collection to get data from each user, like DisplayName and then put that into another collection.

txtPastedText

```
ABC1234
FGH3456
GHI4598
```

`Button OnSelect = ClearCollect(UserIDList,ForAll(Split(txtPastedText.Text, Char(10)),Office365Users.SearchUserV2({searchTerm:ThisRecord.Value})))`

[Collection contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRmub.jpg)
[After Clicking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gOTQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AddColumns and DropColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table-shaping) functions come to your rescue. Using this pattern you could get whatever data you want from the results:

```
DropColumns,
    AddColumns(O365UResults,
        "Email", value.Email,
        "DisplayName", value.DisplayName,
        ...
    ),
    "@odata.nextLink","value"
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up using the below code in a button to create a new collection without sub tables
`ClearCollect(IDList,AddColumns(UserIDList,"Email",First(value).Mail,"DisplayName",First(value).DisplayName))`